# How to make my between statement work in ASP/VB Script

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

This works in Access. I understand that you cannot use the NZ function with ASP/VB Script.

Does anyone know how I could make this SQL statement work in my ASP page using VBSCIPT.

```
BatterGames = rsBatQual("TotalPA")
DIM rsBatterLU, sqlBatterLU

sqlBatterLU = "SELECT games FROM tblLookupPSBatters "
sqlBatterLU = sqlBatterLU & "WHERE ((('" & BatterGames & "') Between Nz([minVal],-999999) And Nz([maxVal],999999)));"

set rsBatterLU = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsBatterLU.Open sqlBatterLU,conn
```

Thanks

Comment: See @Maarten answer. This has nothing to do with ASP/vbScript and everything to do with the flavour of SQL you are using. What type of database are you accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say what your storage is which you use in the ASP-page. If it is SQL Server you can use the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function.

```
BatterGames = rsBatQual("TotalPA")
DIM rsBatterLU, sqlBatterLU

sqlBatterLU = "SELECT games FROM tblLookupPSBatters "
sqlBatterLU = sqlBatterLU & "WHERE ((('" & BatterGames & "') Between ISNULL([minVal],-999999) And ISNULL([maxVal],999999)));"

set rsBatterLU = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")
rsBatterLU.Open sqlBatterLU,conn
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm using Access. I'm getting the following error - Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14' 
Undefined function 'Nz' in expression.

Answer (score 2):

Several functions such as Nz available within MS Access and VBA are not available through OLEDB and ODBC providers. However, there are other options. I'd recommend to use IIf + IsNull combination.

```
SELECT games FROM tblLookupPSBatters
Where Exp Between
IIf(IsNull([minVal]), -999999, [minVal])
And
IIf(IsNull([maxVal]), 999999, [maxVal])
```

A helpful article about this issue : http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/can-i-use-the-nz-function-without-getting-80040e14-errors.html

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help! It was greatly appreciated